# Can't get JAXB to parse XML from Yahoo! Finance to Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to figure out how to get the following XML parsed to a Java class in Eclipse:
http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/aapl/quote?format=xml&view=detail

I tried it following [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/xml/javax_xml_bind_jaxb_unmarshal_url.htm), but I can't get it to work.

I want the name (Apple Inc.) and the price to be parsed.
Here is my Quote Class (tried it with and without annotation parameters):

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Quote")
public class Quote implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private Integer price;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "price")
    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
```

And this is the relevant part of my helper Class, which is planned to store multiple quotes in a set:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXB;
...
            
public class QuoteService {
    Set<Quote> quotes = new LinkedHashSet<>();
                            
    public void initializeQuotes() {
       String s = "http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/aapl/quote?format=xml&view=detail";
                                     
       try {
          URL url = new URL(s);
          Quote quote = JAXB.unmarshal(url, Quote.class);
          quotes.add(quote);
       } 

       catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
        
    public Set<Quote> getQuotes() {
       return quotes;
    }
        
}
```

After executing initializeQuotes(), I do not get any exceptions. However, after printing everything out with the following code:

```
System.out.println(quoteService.getQuotes());

for (Quote quote : quoteService.getQuotes()) {
   System.out.println(quote.getName());
   System.out.println(quote.getPrice());
}
```

I get:

> [quote.core.api.Quote@e36bb2a]
>
> null
>
> null

So, obviously, a Quote Class is created, but its attributes (name and price) are empty instead of containing the corresponding XML values ("Apple Inc." and the current price).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just use this?: http://financequotes-api.com/

Comment: In case I won't be able to get the parsing to work, this seems to do the job as well. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I go to the URL in your code, the XML that comes back is for a "list" object that contains a "resources" object that contains a list of "resource" objects.  That doesn't even remotely match your Java object "Quote" class.

You are much better off starting with a schema that describes the XML you want to convert, and then run that schema through xjc, which is the XML to Java compiler.  That will generate for you the appropriate annotated java object that you can pass to JAXB marshaller/unmarshaller.  (I know the Netbeans IDE will automate for you the step running xjc; other IDEs will probably do that too.)  If you want, you can then start customizing the java classes that it generates - but you'll lose all that if later the schema changes and you have to regenerate the java code.

Now in your case, you are starting with XML, perhaps you don't have a schema. But there's a way around that. Go to http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html and paste in the XML from the Yahoo site. That will generate for you an XML schema that matches the XML you are getting. That should get you going.

I ran through this for the URL you posted, and it worked on the first try.  I didn't actually test unmarshalling the results, but it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I should have mentioned that I will have to implement an option to reload the XML, i.e. via a refresh button in the final application, since it should be able to display real-time quotes. Also, the URL will vary in order to retrieve different stocks.
So, I have to find a way to store the XML in a variable and then convert it to XSD via Java code. I found xsd-gen (https://github.com/wiztools/xsd-gen), but I have read that it might lead to problems. Is there a good way to get this done?

Comment: Trying to dynamically create XSD is not a good idea.  The XSD describes the structure of the XML data that your software has to read and process.  You want your software to automatically figure out how to process the new structure? That's moving into the realm of artificial intelligence.  But don't worry, you can pull new XML and process it as often as you want.  You just need to figure out in advance what the schema (i.e. XSD) is for the various sources that you are going to be pulling data from, and program your software to process that data accordingly.  Does that make sense?